# Android : Precargar imágenes con PICASSO

Tags: android, picasso

estoy haciendo una app que , entre otras cosas me mostrará una serie de imágenes, estoy usando picasso para tratar imágenes que obtengo de un servidor, al inicio del activity, hago un preloader de x segundos y quiero que alli se precarguen las imágenes para que al momento de mostrarlas no me salga ni el placeholder ni en blanco por picasso, esto se puede hacer?

```
/// intento precargar las imágenes
 RequestCreator[] preloadsimgs = new RequestCreator[2];
        preloadsimgs[0] = Picasso.with(this).load("http://lorempixel.com/1200/720/");
        preloadsimgs[1] = Picasso.with(this).load("http://lorempixel.com/1200/720/");
```

///// hago un progress de x segundos ylas envio al imageview:

```
    preloadsimgs[0].placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .fit()
            .error(R.drawable.frameselect)
            .into(firstOptionImg);

    preloadsimgs[1].placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .fit()
            .error(R.drawable.frameselect)
            .into(secondOptionImg);
```

Sin embargo se alcanza a ver el placehorder que es lo que quiero evitar. ( he hehco pruebas con más de 10 segundos, pero obtengo el mismo resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes incluir un `ProgressBar` y ocultarlo cuando la imagen se termina de cargar, usando un callback en el método `into`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ProgressBar" />

</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
preloadsimgs[1].placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .fit()
            .error(R.drawable.frameselect)
            .into(secondOptionImg, new Callback() {
    @Override
    void onSuccess() {
       // ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
       loading.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    @Override
    void onError() {

    }
});
```

Otra opción podría ser usar una librería que soporte el uso de un `ProgressBar` durante la carga como [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/).

Comment: Lo que desea el OP es que las imágenes sean precargadas.

Comment: El dice que está mostrando un `ProgressBar` mientras las imagenes se cargan, sólo que ahora lo muestra durante un tiempo dado (ej: 10 segundos) y a veces eso no es suficiente para terminar la carga. Con éste método el `ProgressBar` se ocultaríá cuando las imagenes hayan terminado de cargar.

Comment: De hecho me gusta tu solución, el progressbar siempre se vera antes de cargar la imagen, pero si la imagen se encuentra en cache, este no se mostrará. Si no hay nada en caché se verá nuevamente el Progressbar.

Comment: primero gracias por las respeustas,s egundo lo que pasa , y tal vez debi mencionar es que uso un viewfliper, entonces cuandoa caba el progressbar pasa a una vista donde están las imágenes y ahi se deberian mostrar, pero alcanza a mostrar los placeholders, intuyo que PICASSO carga Realmente als imagenes cuando estan renderizados los imageview

Comment: Yo dejé de usar Picasso porque inclusive cuando las imágenes estaban cacheadas mostraba el placeholder y demoraba un ratito en cargar. No se si sea un problema de Picasso o de configuración, pero lamentablemente con eso no te puedo ayudar.

Comment: gracias :(, efectivamente con tu metodo de callback puedo ver que  él no las carga totalmente hasta que no se renderiza el view

Comment: @MarianoCórdoba en realidad es el funcionamiento correcto de Picasso, trata de optimizar la carga de 1 a miles de imagenes con buen performance, en realidad su objetivo no es precargarlas.

Comment: @AndressBlend  Si las imágenes son precargadas van a requerir memoria, aún cuando tal vez nunca las tengas que visualizar, lee el comentario que agrego a Mariano, en realidad la respuesta me parece correcta, al menos mostrar el progressbar y al cargar mostrar la imagen.